# Как передать значения для получения нужного queryset?

Tags: python, django

Как мне передать в request.GET параметры, чтобы я мог отфильтровать набор данных. Мну нужно по промежутку даты вытащить нужные данные с базы. Например, с 2020-01-20 по 2020-02-15.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if request.GET['from'] and request.GET['to']:
        return RecognizedObject.objects.filter(created_datetime__gte=from, 
                                               created_datetime__lte=to)
```

Есть пока только такой код в шаблоне откуда будет отправляться request

```
<label for="start">От:</label>
   <input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
          value="2018-07-22"
          min="2015-01-01" max="2020-12-31">

   <label for="finish">До:</label>
   <input type="date" id="finish" name="trip-finish"
          value="2018-07-22"
          min="2015-01-01" max="2020-12-31">

   <button class="submit">Искать</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил сам таким образом:
в views.py

```
class RecognationObjectListView(ListView):
    model = RecognizedObject

    paginate_by = 10
    paginate_orphans = 4

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.GET.get('from') and self.request.GET.get('to'):
            from_date = self.request.GET.get('from')
            to = self.request.GET.get('to')
            print(from_date, to)
            return RecognizedObject.objects.filter(created_datetime__gte=from_date, created_datetime__lte=to)
        return RecognizedObject.objects.filter(created_datetime__lte=timezone.now())
```

в urls.py

```
path('recognized-object/', login_required(views.RecognationObjectListView.as_view(), login_url='login'),
         name='rec_objs_list_url'),
```

в шаблоне для отправки request-a

```
    <form action="" method="GET">
        <label for="finish">От:</label>
        <input type="date" id="start" name="from"
               value="2018-07-22"
               min="2015-01-01" max="2020-12-31">

        <label for="finish">До:</label>
        <input type="date" id="finish" name="to"
               value="2018-07-22"
               min="2015-01-01" max="2020-12-31">

        <input type="submit" value="Искать"/>
    </form>
```